# Is there a way to achieve Flexible Field Templates similar to ACF Flexible Content?

Tags: laravel-backpack

My apologies if this has been asked before. I'm looking for a way to group fields in a flexible way. Much like a repeatable field, but each new row would have the option of being a different pre-defined group of fields.

This is critical with any site I build as it allows the content creators flexibility to re-use components on different "pages" in different orders.

I've been pouring over all the field types and the pagemanager add on trying to figure out a way that I could come up with this type of functionality.

Perhaps I could create a "template" field in the repeatable field that hides/shows certain fields in the group, but the number of fields would stack up and that would have to have javascript to hide/show fields and handle validation. Seems a bit hacky.

Am I missing a solution? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Here's the Nova implementation: https://github.com/whitecube/nova-flexible-content

Wordpress: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/

Craft: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/matrix-fields.html

Comment: Shoot me an email please. We have something 80% done that I think you’ll like.

Comment: Email sent, thank you!